# Verify pem certificate chain using openssl

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, pem

I am trying to write a code which receives a `pcap` file as an input and returns invalid certificates from it.

I have parsed certificate chains, and I'm trying to verify them. 
Because I get the certificates chains out of a `pcap` the chain length are not constant (sometimes they includes only 1 certificate that is selfsigned (and valid)).

Let `cert0.pem` be the servers certificate and `certk.pem` the root CAs certificate.

According to my research online I'm trying to verify the certificate as follows:

1. Create a file `certs.pem` which contains the certificate chain in the order:
    `certk.pem`, `certk-1.pem`,... ,`cert0.pem`
2. use the command (`ca.pem` is a file containing root certificates):

   ```
   openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem certs.pem
   ```

But sometimes the verification goes wrong even for valid certificates, as in the following output:

```
C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA <br>
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate<br> 
error certs.pem: verification failed
```

please help me, how can I verify the certificate chain ?

Additionally is there a way to add a host name verification in the same line? (I have tried to add "`-verify_hostname name`" but again, the output was unexpected).

Comment: the obvious answer is that the CA didn't sign the certs you are verifying - have you checked that?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it, the certificate is valid (it was extracted from ssl traffic to google, and besides verifying it with online certificate checker, the browser didn't alert)

Comment: Now, I tried to repeat the same process in Linux and it actually works. But even copying the folder /etc/ssl/certs to my windows machine and specify it as CApath parameter did not change the output :(